# Safari causes an error when ajax call is made

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, safari

I have the following ajax call:

```
        some_function: function (s) {
            var list = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                url: this.ws_base() + "/webService/someFunction",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ s: s }),
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    list = JSON.parse(data.some_functionResult);
                },
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    this.display_alert("some_function error - readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                }
            });
            return list;
        }
```

On desktop chrome/firefox this will return a long string in json format. Which is what is expected.

In mobile Safari this will return go to the error condition with readyState 0 status 0

I think there has to be some sort of syntax hiccup that Chrome/FF is fine with but in IOS causes the error function to run?

Testing on IOS is hard at my org, so any insight on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: not your question, but using `async: false` is a HORRIBLE thing to do to your users. Keep it async and just handle that properly.

Comment: @RobinZigmond haha I totally agree with you and I'm very much aware that using `async: false` is bad. However this is an older site with an older code base. As much as I'd love to jump through and fix hundreds of ajax calls it just isn't something that I can prioritize for this code base.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your function, you have a ambiguous reference. Where is `this.ws_base()` defined? Also if you're expecting JSON data to be returned, as defined by your `dataType`, why are you then using `JSON.parse()`? If you would like further help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example